# Changing amcharts zoom range fill color

Tags: angular, amcharts4

amcharts allows using the cursor to zoom in, see https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/chart-cursor/#Zooming_panning

When selecting the zoom range, amcharts uses a grey color to highlight the selected.
I would like to change this color, does anyone knows how to do that?

I couldn't find any documentation from amcharts for this configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XYCursor has a [`selection`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/xycursor/#selection_property) sprite object whose properties you can modify, such as the `fill`, `fillOpacity`, etc:

```
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.selection.fill = '#ff0000';
```

Demo below:

```js
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 1),
  "value": 450,
  "value2": 362,
  "value3": 699
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 2),
  "value": 269,
  "value2": 450,
  "value3": 841
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 3),
  "value": 700,
  "value2": 358,
  "value3": 699
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 4),
  "value": 490,
  "value2": 367,
  "value3": 500
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 5),
  "value": 500,
  "value2": 485,
  "value3": 369
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 6),
  "value": 550,
  "value2": 354,
  "value3": 250
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 7),
  "value": 420,
  "value2": 350,
  "value3": 600
}];

// Create axes
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
function createSeries(field, name) {
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
  series.dataFields.valueY = field;
  series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
  series.name = name;
  series.tooltipText = "{dateX}: [b]{valueY}[/]";
  series.strokeWidth = 2;
  
  var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
  bullet.circle.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
  bullet.circle.strokeWidth = 2;
  
  return series;
}

createSeries("value", "Series #1");
createSeries("value2", "Series #2");
createSeries("value3", "Series #3");

chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.selection.fill = '#ff0000';
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: How to maintain the background color  of selected area when releasing zoomin?

Comment: You should post a separate question instead of asking in a comment.

Comment: I have  posted a separate question. Please have a look